# Proper use of asterisk

Tags: vb.net

Dumb question on my part. I have used a '*' many many times, but for the life of me I cannot remember how.

Example:
Text in ComboBox1 is iPad Setup Guide 2015
I want to keep it generic in the code (so if it changes to 2016)

Code I have:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "iPad Setup Guide" Then
```

Code I tried:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "iPad Setup Guide*" Then
If ComboBox1.Text = "iPad Setup Guide" + "*" Then
```

What am I forgetting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of VB.NET's [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator:

```
If ComboBox1.Text Like "iPad Setup Guide*" Then
    ' ...
End If
```

However, for more powerful pattern matching, you may also want to consider using RegEx:

```
If RegEx.IsMatch(ComboBox1.Text, "Pad Setup Guide.") Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Instr

```
If InStr(ComboBox1.Text, "iPad Setup Guide") > 0 Then
```

You could also use LEFT if you wanted to only get things starting with the string as opposed to the string appearing in.